# Как сделать резиновый квадратный DIV css?

Tags: css, html, вёрстка

Как сделать резиновый квадратный DIV css?

Comment: Ну квадратный чтоб был, наверное только средствами JS. В смысле чтоб при растягивании в одну сторону, пропорции сохранялись

Comment: так вот как это сделать, хотя я слышал что это делается и через css... там что-то связано с ограничениями родительского дива

Comment: На ваш вопрос кажется уже отвечали:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css
Фишка в том что padding-bottom и ширина взаимосвязаны, т.е. можно с их помощью любые пропорции соблюдать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position: relative (А еще, например, можно absolute..... тогда нам пофиг на родителя);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

так ? Ну и вроде резиновый.

Comment: так он же не квадратный будет.. стороны будут иметь отношение сторон экрана.. и мне нужно несколько таких квадратиков на странице

Comment: а, сорри :)
Тогда без JS - хз :)

Comment: Автор вопроса, почему отметил это сообщение как лучший? ниже есть гораздо лучшие ответы.

Answer (score 16):

http://jsfiddle.net/fzzxs759/

```css
div {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background: silver;
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Я квадрат</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNEQNL

```
.square { 
border: 5px solid red;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 50vw;
height: 50vw;
}
.content {
font-size: 2em;
padding-top: 20%;
}
```

Вот вам рабочий пример, основанный на использовании vw

Comment: еще бы выравнивание текста по центру добавил, было бы норм

Comment: низкий поклон :)

Answer (score 2):

Если позволяет [поддержка браузерами](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio), то можно так:

```css
div {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  background: silver;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Я квадрат</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

либо дополнительная обертка для элемента либо жс

https://codepen.io/prodavecmacdonalds/pen/ayqWaG

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
}

.container__wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%; /* пропорции блока определяются здесь */
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; /* элемент центрируется */
}

.container__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__wrapper">
        <div class="container__content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать резиновый квадратный DIV css?

Написать две строчки:

```css
div {width: 50%; padding-top: 50%; background: black;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```