# Как сделать чтоб картинка заполнила блок

Tags: css3

Как сделать чтоб картинка заполнила блок,и края скрылись? И чтоб блок не увеличивался. 
И как сделать квадрат? Я не смог, лишь подогнал высоту пикселями.Иначе высота высота подгоняется под картинку.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
div{width:50%;height:300px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="//playcode.io/static/img/fb-static.png"
alt="3212"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать применить [`object-fit: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) для `img`, но не поддерживается IE.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="//playcode.io/static/img/fb-static.png" alt="3212">
</div>
```

Либо сделать `img` как бэкграунд и с помощью [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) свойства (поддерживается с IE9):

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

div.image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('//playcode.io/static/img/fb-static.png');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

В этом случае подгонять `div` под квадрат [не составит труда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450697/235242):

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

div.image {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.square {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.square:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="image square" style="background-image: url('//playcode.io/static/img/fb-static.png');"></div>
```

Также есть и другой вариант решения, который включает в себя написание костылей на JS, но я не вижу целесообразности в его использовании.

Comment: Дело в том что картинку я хотел вставить как анонс статьи.

Comment: @tatunserg вставляйте как `background-image`, в чем проблема? Апдейтнул.

Comment: background-image - не то. Я как-то разобрался,кртинки стали нормально.Если не задавать ширину,то в блоке виден лишь кусок.Если задать ширину 100%, то как-бы  всё хорошо,но стоит уменьшить окно - и в блоках с картинками появляется пустое место. Не понимаю. Облазил cайт w3schools по css - ну не нашёл никакой информации